# AEM 6.5 Image component put extra character

Tags: aem, aem-6

When I add **Image** component, the component itself put an extra character below the image icon. And remains when I go for preview mode. I have added the snapshot below.

[image: Screen_shot]

In preview mode the code appear for this section is also given below

```
<small><div><span class="cq-text-placeholder-ipe">¶</span></div></small>
```

Why does 'Image' component causing the problem?

BTW this component is working for AEM6.4 but not for AEM6.5

Comment: What component is this? Is it coming from AEM Core Components? Using Classic UI for these components is not supported, I am afraid.

Comment: @DawidPura Hi it is not working for both Classic and Touch UI. I believe it is the version related issue. I have updated my Question

Answer (score 0):

From the [AEM community](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/ct-p/adobe-experience-manager-community) I found some guideline. The details [link is here](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/aem-6-5-image-component-put-extra-character/m-p/582687#M37667).

Summary is it is for the version related issue. As this component is working perfectly in 6.4 but not in 6.5(Author mode only). So, What is found there is responsible code in `Image component` code.

```
  Image component

  Draws an image. 

--%><%@ page import="com.day.cq.commons.Doctype,
    com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.DropTarget,
    com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Image, com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Placeholder" %><%
%><%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
    Image image = new Image(resource);
    image.setIsInUITouchMode(Placeholder.isAuthoringUIModeTouch(slingRequest));

    //drop target css class = dd prefix + name of the drop target in the edit config
    image.addCssClass(DropTarget.CSS_CLASS_PREFIX + "image");
    image.loadStyleData(currentStyle);
    image.setSelector(".img"); // use image script
    image.setDoctype(Doctype.fromRequest(request));
    // add design information if not default (i.e. for reference paras)
    if (!currentDesign.equals(resourceDesign)) {
        image.setSuffix(currentDesign.getId());
    }
    String divId = "cq-image-jsp-" + resource.getPath();
    %><div id="<%= xssAPI.encodeForHTMLAttr(divId) %>"><% image.draw(out); %></div><%
    %><cq:text property="jcr:description" placeholder="" tagName="small" escapeXml="true"/>

    <%@include file="/libs/foundation/components/image/tracking-js.jsp"%>
```

So, the above code is for image component and the responsible line is given below. I have removed this line from the code and it is working perfectly. though it is not the best solution, is a fix as of now.

```
<cq:text property="jcr:description" placeholder="" tagName="small" escapeXml="true"/>
```